# Flutter how to hide the autofill options in a TextFormField on flutter-web/iOS

Tags: iphone, flutter, flutter-web

I have a simple Widget, containing a single TextFormField

```
class TestLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  TestLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(),
    ]);
  }
}
```

But when I deploy this on a webserver and access the site from my iPhone, I get the following (see screenshot below):

Note the additional line with autofill related items above the keyboard (password, creditcard and address items and the corresponding 'done' button).  How can I get rid of this line?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating the `keyboardType` property of the `TextFormField`? `keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried it on other simulator/emulator? I guess it's because of your personal iPhone's keyboard config. Try to access it in other device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the keyboardType property to visiblePassword along with enableSuggestions propertie setted to false?

Something like this should fix:

```
TextFormField(
   enableSuggestions: false,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. Note that I'm not so much bothered by the suggestions (yep/ok/I) but more by the three icons on top of it (password, creditcard and location icons)